# Unityでsliderをつくりたいんですが

Tags: unity3d

[【Unity】Sliderの使い方とリアルタイムで値を取得する方法](https://squmarigames.com/2018/12/16/unity-beginner-slider/) を見てコードをかいたんですが

Slider にvalueの定義が含まれておらず、型Slider の最初の引数を受け付けるアクセス可能な拡張メソッドvalue が見つかりませんでした。usingディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が不足していないことを確認してくださいってvisualtudio で書いていました

maxvalue も同じです

どうすればいいですか

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Slider  : MonoBehaviour
{
    Slider hpSlider;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        hpSlider = GetComponent<Slider>();
        float maxHp = 200f;
        float nowHp = 100f;

        //スライダーの最大値の設定
        hpSlider.maxValue = maxHp;

        //スライダーの現在値の設定
        hpSlider.value = nowHp;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: こんなQ&A記事のようにエラーの全文を記載しましょう。[C# VS2019 エラーCS1061の解決方法](https://teratail.com/questions/185939), [error CS1061が出てしまい困っています](https://teratail.com/questions/61774) エラーの説明自体は検索すればここにあります。[コンパイラ エラー CS1061](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061)

Answer (score 2):

【修正された質問記事に対応】

以下の記事と同様の内容と思われます。
[unityのsliderにリアルタイムに反映](https://teratail.com/questions/246811)

ソースコードにて作成しようとしているクラス名が`Slider`で、本当に使おうとしている`UnityEngine.UI.Slider`の短縮形`Slider`と衝突しているためエラーが発生しているのでしょう。
クラス名(およびそれが記述されているファイル名)を`Slider`から変更してください。

またクラス名と.csの前部分のファイル名は大文字小文字も含めて同じ名前にする必要があるようです。

質問の際には、エラーメッセージも含めて、本当に正確な内容を(プライバシーやセキュリティに配慮して)可能な限り詳細に記述してください。

---

【補足】
ちなみに参照先と同様の話題ですがこちらの記事の方が新しそうなので、実際には変わらないかもしれませんが、参考にする元をこちらに変更してみてはどうでしょう？

[Unity：スライダーをHPバーっぽく表示する](https://dianxnao.com/unity%ef%bc%9a%e3%82%b9%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%80%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92hp%e3%83%90%e3%83%bc%e3%81%a3%e3%81%bd%e3%81%8f%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b/)

[Unity：Sliderを使ってボスキャラのHPバーを表現するC#スクリプト](https://dianxnao.com/unity%EF%BC%9Aslider%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%83%9C%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%81%AEhp%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Bc%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF/)

---

**注：**
当初の回答は削除します。
そのため付いているコメントが変な内容に見えるかもしれませんが悪しからず。

Comment: vをVになおすとエラーの文のvalue のvが大文字に変わっただけでした　　　　　　　　　　　　　　visualstudioを使っているんですが、最初の　Slider  hpSlider ;　のところのSlider にカーソルを当てると　class  Slider 　って出たんですけどここのSlider って型名ですか？

Comment: VisualStudioではなくUnityHub＆UnityEditorに切り替えてみるとか。オフィシャルなツールや作り方に沿って作業した方が良いと思われます。

Comment: All Component  errors have to befixed before  you can enter play made!ってエラーが出ました

Comment: 状況の変化はコメントではなく質問記事に追加してください。良くあるエラーのようですが。[Unityよくあるエラー〜"All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!"と “Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script."〜](http://gengoshori.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/05/235414), [【Unity】初心者を潰すAll compiler errors～に遭遇して詰みかけました【初心者記事】](https://qiita.com/unity_mitton/items/aa9d70f92bd65c30ba15), [Unity ビルドエラー All compiler errors have to be fixed before ...](https://mapeli.net/conblo/2019/06/15/unity-builderror-compilererrors/), [\[Unity 5.3.5\]コードに全角スペースが含まれるとAll compiler errors have to be fixed](https://aki-memo.net/995)

Answer (score 0):

https://teratail.com/questions/255001

別のかたに教えていただきました
クラス名とファイル名がSlider だったからでした
クラス名とファイル名を別の名前に変えると解決しました

Comment: 質問記事の内容が実際と違っている(記事では`class Test`でしたが実際は`class Slider`のようですね)のでは回答や助言が的外れになってしまいます。エラーメッセージの件も含めて、本当に正確な内容を(プライバシーやセキュリティに配慮して)可能な限り詳細に記述してください。ちなみに紹介された記事は私が回答に追記した記事を紹介していて同件ですね。